# Do chains of compacts with measure 1 w.r.t. a positive regular probability always have an upper bound when the ordering is the reverse inclusion?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

In a course in Functional Analysis, I tried to prove the following.

**Theorem**

Let $X$ be an LCH (locally compact Hausdorff) space and $\mu$ a positive regular Borel probability measure such that $\mu(A)$ is 0 or 1 for any Borel set of $X$. Then $\mu$ is a Dirac delta.

The professor gave a hint to use Zorn's lemma, so I tried considering $Y=\{K\subset\subset X:\mu(K)=1\}$, ordered by reverse inclusion. $Y$ is nonempty since otherwise $\mu(K)=0$ for all compacts of $X$, but then by regularity $\mu(X)=0$, and $\mu(X)=1$ by hypothesis.

What I got stuck on is the upper bound for chains part. Let $\{K_\alpha\}$ be a chain in $Y$. I want, of course, to take the intersection as an upper bound. It is compact since it is closed (intersection of closed sets, since compact in H space implies closed) in a compact set, any of the $K_\alpha$ works. It is nonempty since by total ordering the elements of the chain have the FIP and they are compact.

But what about the measure? I and the professor both failed to prove it is 1, no matter what we tried. The professor then opened a book to find another argument for what I wanted, which was of course a minimal compact set of measure 1.

But the question remains:

> Can I prove that $Y$ satisfies Zorn?

If I take a countable chain I have continuity from above of $\mu$, but what about the uncountable case? Are there examples of spaces where $Y$ does not satisty Zorn's hypotheses? If so, can you provide such an example? If not, can we prove that any chain has an upper bound, and how?

**Note**

I am NOT asking whether a positive regular Borel probability which assings either 0 or 1 to all Borel sets is a Dirac delta or not, as answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/240411/nu-is-a-dirac-delta). I was trying to prove this and stumbled on an intermediate step I wasn't able to prove valid. Then I found another way, but I want to know if that step could have been done somehow. Repeat: I am asking about the INTERMEDIATE STEP of proving the $Y$ above satisfies Zorn, NOT the theorem I was trying to prove when I bumped into this problematic step.

I hope it is clear now. I mean, this got its title edited to asking for the theorem, and I changed the title in a very long but -- at least I thought, but evidently not -- clear title. It stayed up for ages, and now, two or three days after opening a bounty, I get a comment pointing me to the post linked above, which is, for the present question, at least AFAICT, PLAIN USELESS! So hopefully this note will clarify what I am asking and stop this misunderstanding.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240411/nu-is-a-dirac-delta

Comment: That doesn't answer my question @S.Catterall - see added note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Say the $K_\alpha$ are nested, $\mu(K_\alpha)=1$, and let $K=\bigcap_\alpha K_\alpha$.

Suppose $V$ is open and $K\subset V$. It's enough to show that $\mu(V)\ge1$.

Let $C_\alpha=K_\alpha\setminus V$. Then the $C_\alpha$ are compact and $\bigcap C_\alpha=\emptyset$. But the $C_\alpha$ are also nested, so there exists $\alpha$ with $C_\alpha=\emptyset$. Hence $K_\alpha\subset V$, so $\mu(V)\ge 1$.